# Custom webapp to Magnolia?

Tags: struts, portlet, magnolia

Is it possible to add custom webapps to Magnolia?

I'd like to write a webapp, or portlet which shows TV programs (getting data from own database) and intagrate it into Magnolia.

I have no problem with wrinting the webapp (which could be a struts application, or a portlet). But how to add it to Magnolia?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. 
You can start having a look on pages configuration: your app probably would be a Magnolia Page (mvc). Look for example inside the "Tools" menu: you have a lot of example, with source code available on GIT / SVN.

HTH,
Matteo